# Android: changing the location of an overlay

Tags: android, google-maps, itemizedoverlay

How do i go about changing the location of an overlay. Now, one way is to remove the original overlay n draw a new one. Doing this changes the index of all overlays drawn after it.

For my application, each overlay represent a user with a certain ID. when this user moves, i need to update his location. If i remove the overlay from the list, them the hashmap i am using to locate the overlay for this user, will be rendered useless.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way that I know of. You can simply

```
     // remove the old key association 
     hMap.remove(idForOverlay);
     // add a new one
     hMap.put(idForOverlay, newOverlayItem);
     // add item to the overlays
     mapView.getOverlays().add(newOverlayItem);
     mapView.invalidate();
```

Actually you don't even have to remove() and put() will replace the current association with the newly added association with the key. The current association is returned as an Object

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you can change the overlay point and then call MapView.invalidate.

Comment: but there isn't a method for me to change the overlays location